# Threshold in Pivot

Tags: excel

I am currently analyzing a huge pile of customer data and want to compellingly see which buyers order most from sellers. The logic of my pivot seems to be sound but I would like the pivot to include a threshold to only show values that are bigger than 3. Filtering in the "Count of Customer Name" column unfortunately does not work because of the subcategories.

Here is a sample picture: [image: Example]

I appreciate your help. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

create a helper column along with the source data with identifies the data that is required and use this field in the pivot table. Hope this works

Answer (score 0):

In the filter for Row Labels, select: Value Filters -> Greater Than...

Then, in the dialog, select: Count of Customer Name, is greater than, "5"